# Facebook Graph Request Limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any limit on Facebook graph queries done without access token from server side?

My webapp triggers a graph call like this `graph.facebook.com/userId` that doesn't require any access token.
This call is triggered any time a user vote an image on my FB app.

On [Facebook website](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#policies) they declare a maximum of (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day) which it is quite a lot, unless someone is trying to hack the voting mechanism.

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the access to end point like `graph.facebook.com/userid` doesn't requires any access token as of now but may require the same in future as Facebook APIs are changing constantly.

So it is best advised to access these end points with valid access token, also sometimes you may also face problems in retrieving data from same `graph.facebook.com/userid` end point for some different `userid`. So use some type of access token to retrieve data from these end points.

As such there is no defined limit on the data retrieved without access token on the end points, and for data retrieved from end point with access token it is maximum of (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).